# Error finding matching public key for signature with ubuntu-image device

Tags: snap, ubuntu-core, disk-image

I am following the tutorial for creating a Ubuntu Core image on the Ubuntu website and getting an error. Here is the link to the instructions:
https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/create-model-assertion

The output is the following:

```
kris@devx:~/ubuntu-core-img$ ubuntu-image snap zzz-model.model
[0] make_temporary_directories
[1] determine_output_directory
[2] prepare_image
Error: Error preparing image: cannot fetch and check prerequisites for the model assertion: cannot add assertion model (ubuntu-core-22-intel-iot-edge; series:16 brand-id:zzz): error finding matching public key for signature: found public key "Dzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz" from "Sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" but expected it from: zzz
kris@devx:~/ubuntu-core-img$
```

What does this error mean?